# TypeMock Isolator: WillThrow() bleeds across unit test boundaries?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, isolation, typemock, typemock-isolator

I have two unit tests that use [TypeMock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) to isolate and fake a method from asp.net's SqlMembershipProvider.

In test 1 I have:

```
        Isolate.WhenCalled(
            () =>
                Membership.CreateUser(...)))
            .WithExactArguments()
            .WillThrow(new Exception());
```

In test 2 I have:

```
        Isolate.WhenCalled(
            () =>
                Membership.CreateUser(...)))
            .WithExactArguments()
            .WillReturn(new MembershipUser(...));
```

When I run each test by itself they both pass successfully.

When I run both tests, test number 1 runs first and passes, then test number 2 runs and fails with the exception thrown in test 1.

Why would the `WillThrow()` instruction in test 1 "bleed over" to test 2? After all, test 2 explicitly defines different behavior - `WillReturn()`?

Comment: You haven't included a full snippet, so I'll ask the obvious question... Have the tests/class been marked with the `Isolated` attribute, or are you calling `Isolator.Cleanup` to reset the behaviour? http://www.typemock.com/rule-missing-isolated-attribut

Comment: @forsvarir Thank you. Adding the `[Isolated]` attribute fixed the issue. Would you like to post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If TypeMock behaviours are bleeding between tests, then the first thing to check is that you're cleaning up between tests.  You can do this explicitly by calling `Isolater.CleanUp()`, or using the [preferred approach](http://www.typemock.com/rule-missing-isolated-attribut) which is to decorate either the test methods or the test class itself with the `[Isolated]` attribute.